# How to: Access Controls by using the Controls Collection with page name as string

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Can we access a asp.net page by passing page name as a string and locate controls in the Controls collection. Something like that :

```
    private void GetPageCtrl(string pageName)
    {
// Process pageName
.
.
.
//        

string allTextBoxValues = "";
        foreach (Control c in pageName.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
            {
                if (childc is TextBox)
                {
                    allTextBoxValues += ((TextBox)childc).Text + ",";
                }
            }
        }
        if (allTextBoxValues != "")
        {
            Label1.Text = allTextBoxValues;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what do u mean by Process pageName..?? in your algorithm pageName is a string right..?? what are u doing with that?

Comment: you can do it, just create a new instance of the page, using the page name

Comment: @MuhammadMamoorKhan you are correct but i don't now how I create a new instance of the page which is supply as string